# Select row only 1 time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `tableView` with channels for chat app. When user launches the app, I need to select a first channel as a default. At first I used `willDisplay`, and it worked, but now I decided to update color for unread channels (feature like unread messages). Every time when I call `tableView.reloadData()`, it's select first channel. `selectRow` doesn't work with `willDisplay` for some reasons.

```
let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.selectRow(at: index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
```

.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)
    }
}
```

How should I select first channel only 1 time when user launches the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with calling the `didSelectRowAt` method

```
var isSelected = false

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 && !isSelected  {
      tableView(tableView,didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
      isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Another option is to put this code inside `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear`

```
if !isSelected {
    tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row:0,section:0), animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)
    isSelected = true
}
```